# Javascript find missing select value

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript:

```
var next_user = "1";

    i=0;
    for (i=0;i<=10;i++) 
    {
        var el = document.getElementById("user_list"); 
        var val = el[i].value;

        if (val <= next_user)
        {
            next_user = i;
        }   

        if (val >= next_user)
        {
            next_user = i;
        }   


            alert(next_user);
    }
```

and I have following Select box on the screen:

```
<select id="user_list" onclick="load_user(this)" name="user_list" size="21" style="width:200px;">
<option value="1">Bob</option>
<option value="2">john</option>
<option value="3">Frank</option>
<option value="5">tom</option>
</select>
```

I can't seem to get it working the way I want it to.

The select box could have 10 users in the list and each of the (options) values are unique (1-10).

as you can see in my select box I am missing value 4. My Javascript code from above is meant to go though the select box and find the first value that is missing. (in my above example, it should reply back with 4 as that is missing) but If Bob is missing then it should reply back with 1.

Well that's what my JavaScript code above should be doing but I can't seem to work out what I am doing wrong. (well I hope I am doing it correct)

does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

(I am not plaining to use any jQuery at this stage)

Comment: You are selecting the `select` element and not the `option` elements. .

Comment: maybe by this test : `if(i+1!=val)`? BTW you must write `<10` **or** `i=1` in your loop if you want 10 iterations. Look this link: http://jsfiddle.net/Eu2a2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `options` property of that select element you extracted.

Example:

```
<script>
var userList = document.getElementById("user_list");
for (var i=0;i<userList.options.length; i++) {
    if (userList.options[i].value != (i+1)) {
        alert((i+1)+" is missing");
        break;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to alert the missing Option

```
var next_user = 1;
var el = document.getElementById("user_list");
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var val = parseInt(el[i].value);

    if (val > next_user) {
        alert(next_user);
        break;
    } else {

        next_user++;
    }

}​
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/75kM7/